# Is Stack Overflow a website to ask personal coding questions?

Tags: support

After learning that Stack Overflow is not a question-answer website but rather a website that must ask questions that need to benefit the community, I stopped asking questions at there.

But, say if I had a personal coding question that only I have, and had no idea how to solve the problem. Where would I find a website for this use?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "personal coding question"? Most all questions asked here are in fact questions that come up during one's actual personal programming experience. They should just not be so localized that they don't benefit anybody else.

Comment: A personal question sounds more like it's the purpose of the code that you're referring to, but even personal projects require standard programming problem solving that would still be useful to others. It'll probably depend on how you word it.

Comment: @Pekka, just questions that benefit me and me only

Comment: @Piofmc - can you give an example of such a question?

Comment: @Lix The question would be an entire problem that I would have, for example, if you look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592015/image-for-imagebutton-doesnt-change-as-intended      That would one example, just questions specific to my own problems and not to others.

Comment: That's indeed a borderline question and some users might be tempted to close it as a "debug my code" question. But as @Lix recommends in his answer, it can very likely be broken down into a series of questions that *are* relevant to the wider community with some effort. Try to walk through your code and find out what goes wrong where. When you know that, you may be able to ask: "Why does x do y when I call it with parameter z?" Then the question suddenly becomes relevant, and answerable.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies, I will try to make better questions in the future, and hopefully it would help me and others.

Comment: @Piofmc - BTW, you were 100% correct to come to meta for these types of questions :) Meta is the place we talk *about* [so] and it's usage.

Comment: My oh my.  I remember the good days when we could close because a question was too localized which is pretty much another way to say personal coding questions.  I would guess the answer at this point in time is yes you can ask personal coding questions but it wasn't always this way.  This means that there will likely be mixed reaction.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Questions about personal coding projects are just as welcome on Stack Overflow as those of a professional nature, assuming that your problem is a practical one that might be of interest to other software developers.

Users who are getting their questions closed likely have problems with their questions that are unrelated to the professional or amateur nature of their project.  Writing a good question that is clear, answerable and benefits others is difficult, and this is as true of software developers coding for profit as it is those coding for fun.

Answer (score 12):

The fact that at that time only you have that problem doesn't meant that someone won't have the same issue in the future.

I think you've misinterpreted the real goal here. It is true that all content here *should* benefit the global community of Stack Overflow users but a very personalized question could also help others if formulated correctly.

The actual issue might be with a piece of code that you and **only** you will ever look at, use and maintain. That's pretty much as personal as you can get; Within this code, you might be having a problem that others have already handled in a totally different implementation of similar logic.

If you are able to break down the problem into a small enough form that it *becomes* relevant to others there really is no question too personalized or localized to ask on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 8):

> just questions that benefit me and me only

As others here have said: first, check out whether you can maybe turn your question into one that is more generally applicable. It may not be as hard as you think.

If what you're looking for is really one-on-one-support, say for debugging a block of code, a number of "mentoring" web sites has popped up recently that connect you with experienced programmers for private sessions for a fee.

Examples (that I know of):

- [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io/)
- [AirPair](http://www.airpair.com/)

There are probably others.

There are surely also traditional fora around that might lend themselves more to one-on-one support sessions. This will depend strongly on the tag you're asking the question in.

To some extent, there *may* be private assistance available in the Stack Overflow chat room for that tag, but that's not a given - ask politely and if no one reacts, assume it means "no".